# Inconsistent differential solution involving $~ax' = ab-kx~$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

I have inconsistent problem that involves $~ax'=ab-kx~$. If $~k=0~$ in the first place, I get the expected

$$x=x_0+by$$

However, suppose there is $~k~$, then the solution becomes

$$\int dy=\int\frac{a}{ab-kx}dx$$

$$y=-\frac{a}{k}\ln(\frac{ab-kx}{ab-kx_0})$$

$$x=\frac{ab}{k}+(x_0-\frac{ab}{k})e^{-\frac{k}{a}y}$$

now, if $~k~$ is zero, then I don't recover $~x=x_0+by~$ this baffles me!

I was sure I made the correct integration but the result does not seem to add up resulting to inconsistent answer. Where might probably be the mistake? I want to recover the old solution when I set $~k=0~$.

Comment: Since you divided by $k$ in your derivation, you assumed throughout that $k\ne 0$. In your original simplification, you also assumed $a\ne 0$, of course. What is $m$?  It appeared and then disappeared; I expect you meant it to be $a$.

Comment: I fixed the m now, yes you are correct, but before I integrate it, if I make k=0 then, I still get the solution. However, the problem comes after integration, I think the solution of integral of 1/x equal to ln(x) is fundamentally flawed mathematics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the last line as
$$
x=x_0-ab\frac{e^{-k\frac ya}-1}k
$$
then in the limit $k\to 0$ the last term is to be seen as difference quotient that converges to the derivative $-ab(-\frac ya)=by$ of $-ab\,e^{-k\frac ya}$ at $k=0$.

Comment: Whoa, then that answers it! I thought the differential solution was wrong the whole time. Mathematics is indeed amazingly consistent!

Comment: Ok, this is what I did to make sense of the relationship, apply the limit as k->0 to all terms then the last term is an indefinite fraction so to get the limit, apply L'Hopitals rule w/ respect to k, and viola! You get a consistent answer!

Comment: Applying l'Hôpital to $\frac{f(k)-f(0)}k$ is circular, as the derivative value $f'(0)$ is defined as the limit of that same difference quotient.